# Permission classess decorator is ignored. "Authentication credentials were not provided" response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, permissions

I am using Django Rest Framework for my API service. In my settings.py I've got following REST_FRAMEWORK setting:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    )
    ...
}
```

Now I want to change permission classes to allow anyone to use one view. I had used @permission_classes decorator.

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    @permission_classes([permissions.AllowAny,])
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        ...
```

I should be able to perform create action without any permissions. Instead I receive Authentication error when try to access the API.

```
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
```

According to [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/) @permission_classes decorator is correct way for such permission overriding. This is Django 2.2.4 and DRF 3.10.2.

## EDIT

I forgot to mention that I do not want to allow any one to access any view, only the chosen one. Most of views should have IsAuthenticated permission which is set globally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default permission policy may be set globally, using the DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES setting. For example.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
]}
```

If not specified, this setting defaults to allowing unrestricted access:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
]}
```

for further reference you can check DRF document [doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/)

EDIT:

You can override the permission, with your own class as:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class SkipAuth(permissions.IsAuthenticated):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
    return True
```

And use this class to skip the authentication of particular function as:

```
@permission_classes([SkipAuth])
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
   data = request.data
   ...
```

Comment: You're right but I want the default permission policy to be "IsAuthenticated". AllowAny should be only applied to given method.

Comment: @DanielKusy Just updated my answer. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can just override the get_permission method

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

  serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
  queryset = User.objects.all()

  def get_permissions(self):
    if self.request.method == 'POST':  # remove default permission from post method(Create method)
       return []
    return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes]

  def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = request.data
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You have specified permission class to `IsAuthenticated` but you want to allow it to any users so you have to remove that permission from settings and by default django will allow to any or you can change this to

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
   'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
]
```

See the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/) for more information

Answer (score 2):

In the viewset, you should use `permission_classes` class attribute instead of method decorator.

So your UserViewSet would look like:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        ...
```

In this case, the permission should work as you'd expect.

Comment: Not exactly because now all of my methods in this ViewSet has AllowAny permission, not only create().

Comment: @DanielKusy so you have to create new permission which check the request type and allows/does not allow the request. Example can be `IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly` but you need to do what you want to do there.

Answer (score 2):

You can overwrite `check_permission` method of your desire view function and achieve that.

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def check_permissions(self, request):
       if self.action and (self.action == 'create'):
          return True // allow any
       return super().check_permissions(request)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        ...
```